# Twenty Twelve display only Title and Meta for tag, category, archive results

Tags: wordpress, tags, title, categories

I want to only have the post title and meta (cat, tag, date)  to be displayed on the results page.
I have used this code posted by Esmi at wp-forums to partially achieve this.

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php elseif( !is_category() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>',    'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code in the child theme's content.php will produce Excerpts on the Search page results, but just the Title and Meta for the Category results.

I have tried adding !is_tag || !is_archive   to the elseif statement.. then everything returns the full post.
I have replaced the elseif !is_category with elsif !is_tag and I once again get just the title and meta result on the tag page, which is what I want.

It seems I should be able to add this list to the else if statement to get what I want, but I must not the the correct code to do such.

I also tried replacing the top string php if is_search
with is_search || is_tag || is_archive || is_category
and the gave me whole posts as well.

This should be simple.. but I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.